# How can I delete Time from a DateTime formated CSV

Tags: datetime, powershell, csv, gam

I'll try to describe this accurately. My CSV is in the format:

```
email,            DayMade
email1@email.com, 2013-07-30T15:31:11.000Z
email2@email.com, 3013-07-31T15:31:15.0001
```

That report automatically generates every few days. I need to filter it to delete all entries older than a week. I was told to use the command:

```
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
$Data = Import-CSV "C:\gam\newestreport.csv" | `
Where-Object {$_.Date -as '[DayMade]' -lt $CutoffDate}
```

However, that's returning errors, which I believe are caused by the Time (T15:31:11.0007) being included.

I can't figure out how to remove the time while leaving the date.

Answer (score 3):

In your Where-Object scriptblock, you need to cast the "DayMade" property to a [DateTime] object. Also, when casting, don't enclose the type you are casting to in quotes.

```
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
$Data = Import-CSV "C:\gam\newestreport.csv" | `
Where-Object {$_.DayMade -as [DateTime] -lt $CutoffDate}
```

Comment: `[DateTime]$_.DayMade` would also work and might be a little better to read. If he wants to compare just dates without time he could use `([DateTime]$_.DayMade).Date` and set `$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-5)`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, good point. Note that the explicit cast to DateTime will throw an exception when the string value is not valid, and casting with the "as" operator will not as it will return null (no pun intended).  $null -lt $CutoffDate will return true, so a record with an invalid string in DayMade will be returned using the "as" operator and an exception will be thrown using the explicit cast operator.